# MySQLI in classes and in functions

Tags: php, function, class, syntax, mysqli

My question is rather simple and after checking a few bits and bobs on here I feel its best to ask a new question.

Lets say I have 2 classes

```
class FirstClass {

  function test() {
    return "info";
  }

}

class SecondClass {

  function test() {
    return "info";
  }

}
```

Then I have my mysqli object

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, user, password, db);
```

What do i need to do to be able to use the mysqli object inside the functions inside the classes.

This is my 2 thoughts so far although I haven't placed it on a site for testing yet.

```
class FirstClass {
global $mysqli;

  function test() {
    $mysqli->query("some query");
    return "info";
  }

}
```

or

```
class FirstClass {

  function test() {
    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli->query("some query");
    return "info";
  }

}
```

I am pretty sure I can setup a construct if need be but I just need to know which way is the best way/only way to share the mysqli object.

Thanks

---

EDIT:

So I have done a hell of a load of learning and now have a lot more experience with passing info in and out.

Here is a latest working example type that I use.

```
namespace Page;
use mysqli;

class edit extends details{
  protected $db;

  //this function is actually in the details class but there is no point in demoing 2 classes
  function __construct(mysqli $con){
    $this->db = $con;
  }
}
```

Comment: the *mysqli* should be a field in the class. So, you don't need to use a **global** variable.

Comment: all info is good info, thanks @Kneel-Before-ZOD

Comment: as everyone seems to be voting this question down and I have NO idea why, I am voting to take it down before I have no rep left!

Comment: Strictly speaking, this answer has been asked too many times already to tolerate another duplicate. That;s most probable reason for downvotes.

Comment: Honestly. The question doesn't deserve a downvote. It's a valid question. Well formed, and many of the 'answers' out there provide the manual. If he knew from the manual he would have utilized it there and not asked. An answer to someone else may seem easy to one, but not necesarily another. Up-voting to counterbalance.

Comment: @MorganGreen you are supposed to read the site rules too. *Before* starting any activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand what Kneel told you in comments and to counter the other answer

```
class foo {

  function __construct($mysqli){
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
  }

  function test() {
    return $this->mysqli->query("some query");
  }

}
```

is what it have to be.
You should create a mysqli instance somewhere outside the class and then pass it in coustructor.

Comment: ok, thanks. Do you not have to pass it to a declared `var $mysqli` first or can you declare on the fly as you have done with `$this->mysqli`

Comment: Once I have tested this, you will probably get the answer. Very simplistic. Can you confirm my thoughts from the first comment though?

Comment: I just can't get what is asked there

Comment: Do I have to declare the variable or should I go straight to $this->mysqli and assume this creates a declaration?

Comment: Just make it exactly as in the example above

Comment: I have added as above + declaration and as soon as I get back to a pc to test I will try with declaration and without just to see what happens. Generally other languages prefer you to declare then assign such as c# hence the question

Comment: ah I see now. Yes, you may declare it

Answer (score 0):

You could use `__construct()` to initialize your MYSQLi. You can then access it around your class with `$this`.

```
class FirstClass {

  public function __construct(){
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");
  }

  function test() {
    $this->mysqli->query("some query");
    return "info";
  }

}
```

If you wanted to use it in your second class too, you could construct it in the same way or extend your first class.

```
class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function test() {
    return "info";
  }

}
```

Comment: so I assume you would then access the connection from outside the class by calling any class that has its parents construct. I guess this means outer coding should using a mysqli class in that case for things like queries? Classes are fairly new to me in the php context